# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' In Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm getting this **error** in my Jupyter Notebook. The complete error is bellow:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 import numpy as np # working with data
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
      4 from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
      5 from keras.models import Sequential

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in 
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in 
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 from . import losses_utils
      8 from . import metrics_utils

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in 
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in 
----> 1 from .load_backend import epsilon
      2 from .load_backend import set_epsilon
      3 from .load_backend import floatx
      4 from .load_backend import set_floatx
      5 from .load_backend import cast_to_floatx

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py in 
     88 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     89     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 90     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     91 else:
     92     # Try and load external backend.

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in 
      3 from __future__ import print_function
      4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
      7 from tensorflow.python.framework import device as tfdev

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

In **cmd:** My python version is:

```
C:\Users\casper>python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

Anaconda version:

```
C:\Users\casper>conda --version
conda 4.5.4
```

In **Anaconda Prompt** I install Tensorflow like below:

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6  
// CPU edition    
pip install -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple tensorflow
```

In **Anaconda Prompt**: My Tensorflow version is:

```
(base) C:\Users\casper>activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\Users\casper>python
Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 12:30:02) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2020-02-14 19:36:32.468120: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-02-14 19:36:32.474896: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
>>> tf.__version__
'2.1.0'
>>> tf.__path__
['D:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow']
```

It's really the first time I'm working with all these libraries and technologies, I lost the track, I can see all around its different Python versions, It's really messed up for me now. How could I fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried opening a new terminal within Jupyter and then executing `pip freeze` from there to inspect.  I had an issue before where I needed to install within the Jupyter terminal specifically

Comment: Did you select the rigth kernel in Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: I made a stupid mistake, I forgot to change the kernel. Thnx @Philip How could i accept it as an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember to change to the right kernel. You can do that in Jupyter Notebook, by pressing `Kernel`. Then select `Change kernel` and select your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Anaconda as admin (right-click -> run as administrator).
And try these commands as well (taken from the Anaconda Documentation):

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

You may need to restart you PC.